# I want to fill an 6x6 grid with Shapes in Unity3D

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, matrix

I'm trying to develop a game which uses Tetris-like blocks in a 6x6 "module".

[A basic module is something like this ;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvYRk.png)

I thought that I could create a 6x6 matrix and shapes represented like this;

```
Matrix =
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

And for shapes (example "L")

```
L =
[1,0]
[1,0]
[1,1]
```

Then filling the 6x6 matrix with shapes (There are 24 of them).

The problem is, I really don't know what to do. I'm a high school senior student who never experienced that kind of problem. I want to know how to approach that kind of problem and apply it on my game.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What I would do in this situation: create a bunch of prefabs for each figure, and add them to list inside some "gameManager" class. Are you dealing with 2d or 3d? In another words will those figures be flat or from cube base?

Comment: You should at least try to code something and post your attempt so we may help you. Such matrixes are best stored in two dimensional arrays or lists and iterated with some kind of loop - where you instance your cube instance on positions based on your matrix. Just add x-size of your cube in the first dimension and z-size for the other and alter the coordinates of your instance accordingly. Shouldn't be hard when you begin at 0,0,0.